# Get user shared tasks from Outlook interop using C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I try to get user shared tasks from Outlook.
I wrote the code that can get tasks from MAPI folder (`LoadTasksFromFolder` method). I try to get all user shared folders.
But I do not know in advance what and how many recipients will be.
How I can get all Recipients, who shared tasks for current user or get tasks from shared folders?

```
Outlook.Recipient recipient = store.Session.CreateRecipient("user@domain.com");
recipient.Resolve();
if (recipient.Resolved)
{
  var sharedFolder = store.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
  LoadTasksFromFolder(sharedFolder, dbTasks, categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem:

```
var module = (Outlook.TasksModule)oApp.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleTasks);
foreach (Outlook.NavigationGroup navigationGroup in module.NavigationGroups)
  {
    foreach (Outlook.NavigationFolder navigationFolder in navigationGroup.NavigationFolders)
    {   
      LoadTasksFromFolder(navigationFolder.Folder,dbTasks,navigationFolder.Session.Categories);
    }
  }
```